# ¿Cómo añadir un padding a la segunda linea de un párrafo?

Tags: css

Estoy intentando hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Concretamente, que el texto acabe en "..."  por no entrar todo en la caja plegada, pero que deje hueco para el "ver más"  abajo a la derecha.

Mi intento es el siguiente. Con

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
```

en el padre del `<p>` que ha de cortarse, consigo que la ellipsis esté en la 2nda linea... pero no se cómo hacer el hueco.

```css
.caja {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 22px 10px 56px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e6f9fa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(153, 150, 153, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(153, 150, 153, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(153, 150, 153, 1);
}

.caja.plegado {
  height: 93px;
}

.caja.desplegado {
  height: 187px;
}

.caja p.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: #152a35;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin : unset;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.caja p.texto {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: #152a35;
  padding: unset;
  position: relative;
}

.caja p.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ff7000;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.caja p.toggle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: 9px 8px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAERlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAAEKADAAQAAAABAAAAEAAAAAA0VXHyAAAAoUlEQVQ4EWNgGAWMuILgfwmDGMNfhnVgeQ6GQMZ2htfY1GI1AKp5H8N/Bm2opisMnAxO2AxhQjcVTfMVBkaGq0A1OgzfGfb9r2QQRVePYgCGZqCtDMxAjMcQuBewaYY5GZ8c2AB8CmBORlEDchEHgyPIAogX/jKshwYYzsBi7GF4BfcOKHB/APUAASwMPgD9eRRXSMNcgWTIUaDYB5j4SKcBw3JNWr+VO8cAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}

.caja.plegado p.toggle:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.caja>div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 1.625;
  height: 52px;
}

.caja.desplegado>div {
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
}



.caja.desplegado p.toggle.mas,
.caja.plegado p.toggle.menos {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja plegado">


  <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <div>
    <p class="texto">
      Nam tellus ligula, scelerisque quis velit eu, venenatis dictum dui. Vestibulum nibh leo, consectetur in odio sed, tristique ullamcorper urna. Nullam ullamcorper rutrum arcu. Mauris accumsan lectus est, finibus iaculis felis faucibus vel. Nullam lacus enim, gravida vitae pharetra iaculis, varius vitae urna. Sed id fringilla enim. Nunc ut massa id lorem porttitor mollis. Nulla bibendum purus in mollis consectetur. Curabitur ac odio a sapien consectetur rhoncus. Morbi nec magna at urna dignissim aliquet.
    </p>
  </div>

  <p class="toggle mas">Ver más</p>
  <p class="toggle menos">Ver menos</p>

</div>
```

Como veis, queda así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Notas:**

- El texto ha de ser un solo `<p>` para que sea responsive.  Si no fuera responsive, separaria el texto en 2 `<p>`'s para que el primero tenga el 100% del `width` y el segundo algo menos para el hueco.
- Busco una solución que sea 100%  CSS
- Es imprescindible que el "Ver más" vaya en la misma linea que la 2nda linea del párrafo. Peticiones de cliente ‍♂

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única solución que se me ocurre es una chapuza que da el pego, y es poner un pseusoelemento del `<p>` para que tape con el color azul de la caja las ultimas palabras y así simular ese hueco.

El problema será que pueda cortar una letra a la mitad

```
.caja.plegado p.texto:after {
    content: '...';
    text-align: left;
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #e6f9fa;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```css
.caja {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 22px 10px 56px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e6f9fa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(153, 150, 153, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(153, 150, 153, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(153, 150, 153, 1);
}

.caja.plegado {
  height: 93px;
}

.caja.plegado p.texto:after {content: '...';text-align: left;width: 80px;position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;background: #e6f9fa;padding-left: 5px;}

.caja.desplegado {
  height: 187px;
}

.caja p.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: #152a35;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin : unset;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.caja p.texto {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: #152a35;
  padding: unset;
  position: relative;
}

.caja p.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ff7000;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.caja p.toggle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: 9px 8px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAERlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAAEKADAAQAAAABAAAAEAAAAAA0VXHyAAAAoUlEQVQ4EWNgGAWMuILgfwmDGMNfhnVgeQ6GQMZ2htfY1GI1AKp5H8N/Bm2opisMnAxO2AxhQjcVTfMVBkaGq0A1OgzfGfb9r2QQRVePYgCGZqCtDMxAjMcQuBewaYY5GZ8c2AB8CmBORlEDchEHgyPIAogX/jKshwYYzsBi7GF4BfcOKHB/APUAASwMPgD9eRRXSMNcgWTIUaDYB5j4SKcBw3JNWr+VO8cAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}

.caja.plegado p.toggle:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.caja>div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 1.625;
  height: 52px;
}

.caja.desplegado>div {
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
}



.caja.desplegado p.toggle.mas,
.caja.plegado p.toggle.menos {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja plegado">


  <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <div>
    <p class="texto">
      Nam tellus ligula, scelerisque quis velit eu, venenatis dictum dui. Vestibulum nibh leo, consectetur in odio sed, tristique ullamcorper urna. Nullam ullamcorper rutrum arcu. Mauris accumsan lectus est, finibus iaculis felis faucibus vel. Nullam lacus enim, gravida vitae pharetra iaculis, varius vitae urna. Sed id fringilla enim. Nunc ut massa id lorem porttitor mollis. Nulla bibendum purus in mollis consectetur. Curabitur ac odio a sapien consectetur rhoncus. Morbi nec magna at urna dignissim aliquet.
    </p>
  </div>

  <p class="toggle mas">Ver más</p>
  <p class="toggle menos">Ver menos</p>

</div>
```